# Saving the content from a Textarea dont works

Tags: panels, input-formats

An **Textfield** within my **Custom Content Pane** works fine.

An **Textarea** incl. input-filter ('#type' => 'text_format',) will not be saved.

```
<?php
  function text_edit_form($form, &$form_state) {
      $conf = $form_state['conf'];

      $form['form_text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => t('Text'),
        '#format' => 'filtered_html',
        '#size' => 50,
        '#resizeable' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => !empty($conf['form_text']) ? $conf['form_text'] : '',
      );

      return $form;
    } 
  function text_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    foreach (array('form_text') as $key) {
      $form_state['conf'][$key] = $form_state['values'][$key];
    }
  }
?>
```

At drupal.com somebody wrotes, that #default_value expect and string, but text_format is an array. So he postet the following solution.

But how can I build that within my hook_edit_form?

```
<?php
      // Retrieve the default values for 'value' and 'format', if not readily
      // available through other means:
      $defaults = array(
        'value' => '',
        'format' => filter_default_format(),
      );
      $my_richtext_field = variable_get('my_richtext_field', $defaults);
      // Just construct a regular #type 'text_format' form element:
      $form['my_richtext_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => t('My richtext field'),
        '#default_value' => $my_richtext_field['value'],
        '#format' => $my_richtext_field['format'],
      );
 ?>
```

Who can help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

I just rebuild the save-stuff:

```
<?php
function text_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['conf']['form_text'] = $form_state['values']['form_text']['value'];
}
?>
```